# How do I set a variable in a way that a cmake find_package library can use it?

Tags: cmake

I'm using a cmake find_package script (the exact one probably isn't terribly important, but it's https://raw.githubusercontent.com/snikulov/cmake-modules/master/FindFFmpeg.cmake) that uses a variable:

```
if (NOT FFmpeg_FIND_COMPONENTS)
  set(FFmpeg_FIND_COMPONENTS AVCODEC AVFORMAT AVUTIL)
endif ()
```

Obviously the intent is that the caller be able to override the list of components to look for, based on the project's requirements.

So I do that from my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(FFmpeg_FIND_COMPONENTS AVCODEC AVFORMAT AVUTIL SWRESAMPLE SWSCALE)
find_package(FFmpeg)
```

But the new value is ignored, and the script behaves as if `FFmpeg_FIND_COMPONENTS` wasn't customized.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `<package>_FIND_COMPONENTS` is filled with the value of *COMPONENTS* option of the `find_package`:

```
find_package(FFmpeg COMPONENTS AVCODEC AVFORMAT AVUTIL SWRESAMPLE SWSCALE)
```

See [find_package documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_package.html) for more details.